# How do I count the number of agents that passed through a state from the statechart in Anylogic?

Tags: java, count, anylogic, statechart

I wanna count the number of agents that passed through a state in a day from the statechart.
and then I show them by a plot chart or time stack chart. I define some code in the state. Do they can effect on count the number of agents that passed through this state in a day? How do I count the number of agents that passed through a state from the statechart in Anylogic?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can just count agents by adding a variable and let it [count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMB3P.jpg) wherever you want to. In this case I added a variable named "countAgents" on main and let it count the number of "myAgents" moving from state to state 1.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much. My problem is solved by your answer.